# How to compute projections of 3D meshes in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, projection, mesh

I'm trying to compute 2d projections of a 3d mesh from different views using matlab.
The solution I m using now, is to plot the 3d mesh, rotate it, and make a screenshot.

I would like to know if there is any matlab internal functions or any other solution that allow me, given a set of vertices and triangles, to compute the projections without having to plot the 3D mesh

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`view`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/view.html) command to rotate the axes and change the viewpoint. The azimuth and elevation are given in degrees (ref. documentation for more info). Here's a small example:

```
ha=axes;
[x,y,z]=peaks;
surf(x,y,z);
xlabel('x');ylabel('y');zlabel('z')

%#projection on the X-Z plane
view(ha,[0,0])

%#projection on the Y-Z plane
view(ha,[90,0])

%#projection on the X-Y plane
view(ha,[0,90])
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

### Projections on different 2D planes

#### X-Z

[image]

#### Y-Z

[image]

#### X-Y

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I m already using the view command in a loop to get all the views of the 3D mesh. I m looking for a solution that allow me to get all the views without ploting the mesh.Something like reading the pojection from a buffer (like iin opengl)

Comment: @mchahhou: You can call your `figure` with the `visible` property set to `off` i.e., `hf=figure('visible','off');` In this case the figure will not be plotted on screen (saving considerable time if used in a loop), but you can still save it/print it/change views etc.