# How to calculate the projected area of a 3d mesh with a particular view angle?

Tags: view, 3d, 2d, mesh, projection

My question is close to the question asked at [How to compute projections of 3D meshes in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180841/how-to-compute-projections-of-3d-meshes-in-matlab), but I think the answer is not clear. I need to calculate the projected 2d area (i.e. the area of the mesh displayed by 'view' at a particular angle). How can I get this area?

Comment: That depends on the projection. If it's a orthogonal projection, then it's as simple as `cos(alpha)` with alpha being the view angle. For affine perspective projection things get a bit messier.

Comment: @datenwolf could you please elaborate? For example, how can we calculate the 2d projected area on a xy plane (viewed along z-axis)? I need the projected total area of a 3d mesh in 2d.